# Total order and Total relation

Tags: relations

What is the difference between total order and total relation? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A total order relation is a total relation that is also *transitive* and *anti-symmetric*.

Therefore the difference is we dropped the requirements of transitivity and anti-symmetry.

---

Formally for any binary relation $R$ on $X$ we have in the language of relation algebra:

$$R\text{ is a total order on }X\iff (R\cup R^{-1}=X\times X)\land (R\circ R\subseteq R)\land (R\cap R^{-1}=\text{id}_X)$$
$$R\text{ is total on }X\iff (R\cup R^{-1}=X\times X)$$

Answer (score 3):

Every total order is a total relation.

However a total relation need not be a total order.

For example, let $S = \{1,2\}$, and consider the relation $R$ on $S$ given by
$$R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$
Clearly, $R$ is a total relation on $S$.

But $R$ is not anti-symmmetric, since $1\,R\,2$ and $2\,R\,1$, but $1 \ne 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the first sentence of each link you provided:

> In mathematics, a binary relation R over a set X is total or complete if for all a and b in X, a is related to b or b is related to a (or both).

and compare it to:

> In mathematics, a linear order, total order, simple order, or (non-strict) ordering is a binary relation on some set $X$, which is **antisymmetric, transitive, and total**

---

In other words, a total order is a total relation with additional properties, meaning every total order is a total relation, but not every total relation is a total order.